# Changes to kotlin class not recognized by Spring Boot?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, spring-tool-suite

Changes are not reflected in the service response from `http://localhost:8080/hi` after:

1. Modifying the response string of `SomeController` in the code below
2. Spring Tool Suite automatically compiles the changes
3. Spring Boot DevTools automatically restarts the server
4. Request to `http://localhost:8080/hi` still gives the old response

Somehow they're getting cached, even after running `./gradlew build` manually.

Totally different issues: I have Java 1.8 JRE and JDK installed into two directories under `Program Files\Java`. The project shows the **JRE** dependency and running `build` from STS `Gradle Tasks` window yields the **JRE** instead of the **JDK**, even though `JAVA_HOME` is properly set to the JDK, STS is configured to use the JDK by default (JRE unchecked), and the Spring Boot Project is configured to use the workspace settings (JDK). It seems to be picking up the JRE from the IDE runtime itself, instead of from the settings? I found a work-around by right-clicking the `build` task and selecting `build -> Open Gradle Run Configuration -> Java Home` and manually setting this to the same directory as the JDK. I also found a workaround for the project with right-click on project `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries`, removing `JRE System Library` and adding the JDK (`Add Library... -> JRE System Library -> Workspace default JRE (jdk1.8.0_144)`). But, sometimes the project resets itself to the JRE somehow.

```
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 4.5.1
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171
```

## Code

```
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class SomeController {
    @GetMapping("/hi")
    fun hi(): String {
        return "hey"
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
open class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

## Configuration

- Windows 10 Pro
- Spring Tool Suite 3.9.4.RELEASE
- JDK 1.8
- Kotlin 1.2.41
- Gradle Wrapper 4.5.1
- Spring Boot + DevTools 2.0.3.RELEASE

## Setup Steps

1. New workspace in STS with Gradle Buildship and Kotlin extensions
2. Add JDK 1.8 as default
3. Create project `File -> New -> Spring Starter Project`

   - Gradle (Buildship 2.x)
   - Java 8
   - Kotlin
   - Reactive Web
   - DevTools
   - Actuator
4. Right-click project `Configure Kotlin -> Add Kotlin Nature`
5. Start service `Boot Dashboard -> local -> demo [devtools] [:8080]`